# How do I modify an existing Amazon Cloudfront Distribution?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, aws-cli

I'm trying to modify an existing Amazon Cloudfront distribution. It always fails. Why?

```
result = client.get_distribution(Id=env_vars['CLOUDFRONT_ID'])
etag = result['ETag']
existing_config = result['Distribution']['DistributionConfig']
existing_config['CallerReference'] = str(datetime.datetime.utcnow())

client.update_distribution(DistributionConfig=existing_config, Id=env_vars['CLOUDFRONT_ID'], IfMatch=etag)
```

**Result**:

`botocore.errorfactory.IllegalUpdate: An error occurred (IllegalUpdate) when calling the UpdateDistribution operation: You cannot update Origin or CallerReference.`

Comment: Why are you doing this? 
 `existing_config['CallerReference'] = str(datetime.datetime.utcnow())`

Comment: Because the documents say that `CallerReference` should be a unique value. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet1/latest/apidocs/html/P_Amazon_CloudFront_2012_03_15_Model_CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentityConfig_CallerReference.htm

Comment: Not for updates.  For updates, it needs to be the same.

Comment: Is that documented anywhere?

Comment: @ChrisB. I also had an issue when updating a distribution. All you have to do is get the current reference and use that value when updating the distribution. Documentation for the the API call: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateDistribution.html